# plotting stacked & mulitple bar charts from multi-indexed dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

```html
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>1-RM</th>
      <th>2-RM</th>
      <th>3-RM</th>
      <th>4-RM</th>
      <th>5-RM</th>
      <th>EXEC</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>2005</th>
      <td>{'ANG MO KIO': 0, 'BEDOK': 0, 'BISHAN': 0, 'BUKIT BATOK': 0, 'BUKIT MERAH': 0, 'BUKIT PANJANG': 0, 'BUKIT TIMAH': 0, 'CENTRAL': 0, 'CHOA CHU KANG': 0, 'CLEMENTI': 0, 'GEYLANG': 0, 'HOUGANG': 0, 'JURONG EAST': 0, 'JURONG WEST': 0, 'KALLANG': 0, 'LIM CHU KANG': 0, 'MARINE PARADE': 0, 'PASIR RIS': 0, 'PUNGGOL': 0, 'QUEENSTOWN': 0, 'SEMBAWANG': 0, 'SENGKANG': 0, 'SERANGOON': 0, 'TAMPINES': 0, 'TOA PAYOH': 0, 'WOODLANDS': 0, 'YISHUN': 0}</td>
      <td>{'ANG MO KIO': 0, 'BEDOK': 0, 'BISHAN': 0, 'BUKIT BATOK': 0, 'BUKIT MERAH': 0, 'BUKIT PANJANG': 0, 'BUKIT TIMAH': 0, 'CENTRAL': 0, 'CHOA CHU KANG': 0, 'CLEMENTI': 0, 'GEYLANG': 0, 'HOUGANG': 0, 'JURONG EAST': 0, 'JURONG WEST': 0, 'KALLANG': 0, 'LIM CHU KANG': 0, 'MARINE PARADE': 0, 'PASIR RIS': 0, 'PUNGGOL': 0, 'QUEENSTOWN': 0, 'SEMBAWANG': 0, 'SENGKANG': 0, 'SERANGOON': 0, 'TAMPINES': 0, 'TOA PAYOH': 0, 'WOODLANDS': 0, 'YISHUN': 0}</td>
      <td>{'ANG MO KIO': 800.0, 'BEDOK': 800.0, 'BISHAN': 780.0, 'BUKIT BATOK': 748.33, 'BUKIT MERAH': 816.67, 'BUKIT PANJANG': 0, 'BUKIT TIMAH': 0, 'CENTRAL': 0, 'CHOA CHU KANG': 0, 'CLEMENTI': 832.67, 'GEYLANG': 800.0, 'HOUGANG': 0, 'JURONG EAST': 791.67, 'JURONG WEST': 783.33, 'KALLANG': 800.0, 'LIM CHU KANG': 0, 'MARINE PARADE': 866.67, 'PASIR RIS': 0, 'PUNGGOL': 0, 'QUEENSTOWN': 850.0, 'SEMBAWANG': 0, 'SENGKANG': 0, 'SERANGOON': 0, 'TAMPINES': 816.67, 'TOA PAYOH': 816.67, 'WOODLANDS': 0, 'YISHUN': 737.67}</td>
      <td>{'ANG MO KIO': 941.67, 'BEDOK': 916.67, 'BISHAN': 1016.67, 'BUKIT BATOK': 908.33, 'BUKIT MERAH': 1000.0, 'BUKIT PANJANG': 0, 'BUKIT TIMAH': 0, 'CENTRAL': 0, 'CHOA CHU KANG': 883.33, 'CLEMENTI': 1016.67, 'GEYLANG': 975.0, 'HOUGANG': 876.67, 'JURONG EAST': 1000.0, 'JURONG WEST': 950.0, 'KALLANG': 1000.0, 'LIM CHU KANG': 0, 'MARINE PARADE': 0, 'PASIR RIS': 903.33, 'PUNGGOL': 0, 'QUEENSTOWN': 1100.0, 'SEMBAWANG': 0, 'SENGKANG': 0, 'SERANGOON': 926.67, 'TAMPINES': 941.67, 'TOA PAYOH': 966.67, 'WOODLANDS': 850.0, 'YISHUN': 850.0}</td>
      <td>{'ANG MO KIO': 0, 'BEDOK': 1033.33, 'BISHAN': 1150.0, 'BUKIT BATOK': 0, 'BUKIT MERAH': 0, 'BUKIT PANJANG': 0, 'BUKIT TIMAH': 0, 'CENTRAL': 0, 'CHOA CHU KANG': 941.67, 'CLEMENTI': 0, 'GEYLANG': 0, 'HOUGANG': 915.0, 'JURONG EAST': 1044.0, 'JURONG WEST': 1025.0, 'KALLANG': 0, 'LIM CHU KANG': 0, 'MARINE PARADE': 0, 'PASIR RIS': 958.33, 'PUNGGOL': 0, 'QUEENSTOWN': 0, 'SEMBAWANG': 900.0, 'SENGKANG': 895.0, 'SERANGOON': 0, 'TAMPINES': 1033.33, 'TOA PAYOH': 0, 'WOODLANDS': 900.0, 'YISHUN': 900.0}</td>
      <td>{'ANG MO KIO': 0, 'BEDOK': 0, 'BISHAN': 0, 'BUKIT BATOK': 0, 'BUKIT MERAH': 0, 'BUKIT PANJANG': 0, 'BUKIT TIMAH': 0, 'CENTRAL': 0, 'CHOA CHU KANG': 0, 'CLEMENTI': 0, 'GEYLANG': 0, 'HOUGANG': 0, 'JURONG EAST': 0, 'JURONG WEST': 0, 'KALLANG': 0, 'LIM CHU KANG': 0, 'MARINE PARADE': 0, 'PASIR RIS': 1050.0, 'PUNGGOL': 0, 'QUEENSTOWN': 0, 'SEMBAWANG': 0, 'SENGKANG': 0, 'SERANGOON': 0, 'TAMPINES': 0, 'TOA PAYOH': 0, 'WOODLANDS': 1012.5, 'YISHUN': 0}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2006</th>
      <td>{'ANG MO KIO': 0, 'BEDOK': 0, 'BISHAN': 0, 'BUKIT BATOK': 0, 'BUKIT MERAH': 0, 'BUKIT PANJANG': 0, 'BUKIT TIMAH': 0, 'CENTRAL': 0, 'CHOA CHU KANG': 0, 'CLEMENTI': 0, 'GEYLANG': 0, 'HOUGANG': 0, 'JURONG EAST': 0, 'JURONG WEST': 0, 'KALLANG': 0, 'LIM CHU KANG': 0, 'MARINE PARADE': 0, 'PASIR RIS': 0, 'PUNGGOL': 0, 'QUEENSTOWN': 0, 'SEMBAWANG': 0, 'SENGKANG': 0, 'SERANGOON': 0, 'TAMPINES': 0, 'TOA PAYOH': 0, 'WOODLANDS': 0, 'YISHUN': 0}</td>
      <td>{'ANG MO KIO': 0, 'BEDOK': 0, 'BISHAN': 0, 'BUKIT BATOK': 0, 'BUKIT MERAH': 0, 'BUKIT PANJANG': 0, 'BUKIT TIMAH': 0, 'CENTRAL': 0, 'CHOA CHU KANG': 0, 'CLEMENTI': 0, 'GEYLANG': 0, 'HOUGANG': 0, 'JURONG EAST': 0, 'JURONG WEST': 0, 'KALLANG': 0, 'LIM CHU KANG': 0, 'MARINE PARADE': 0, 'PASIR RIS': 0, 'PUNGGOL': 0, 'QUEENSTOWN': 0, 'SEMBAWANG': 0, 'SENGKANG': 0, 'SERANGOON': 0, 'TAMPINES': 0, 'TOA PAYOH': 0, 'WOODLANDS': 0, 'YISHUN': 0}</td>
      <td>{'ANG MO KIO': 830.0, 'BEDOK': 812.5, 'BISHAN': 0, 'BUKIT BATOK': 800.0, 'BUKIT MERAH': 912.5, 'BUKIT PANJANG': 0, 'BUKIT TIMAH': 0, 'CENTRAL': 0, 'CHOA CHU KANG': 0, 'CLEMENTI': 877.5, 'GEYLANG': 818.75, 'HOUGANG': 765.0, 'JURONG EAST': 800.0, 'JURONG WEST': 800.0, 'KALLANG': 862.5, 'LIM CHU KANG': 0, 'MARINE PARADE': 906.25, 'PASIR RIS': 0, 'PUNGGOL': 0, 'QUEENSTOWN': 898.75, 'SEMBAWANG': 0, 'SENGKANG': 0, 'SERANGOON': 800.0, 'TAMPINES': 850.0, 'TOA PAYOH': 875.0, 'WOODLANDS': 0, 'YISHUN': 766.0}</td>
      <td>{'ANG MO KIO': 975.0, 'BEDOK': 971.25, 'BISHAN': 1056.25, 'BUKIT BATOK': 975.0, 'BUKIT MERAH': 1085.5, 'BUKIT PANJANG': 0, 'BUKIT TIMAH': 0, 'CENTRAL': 0, 'CHOA CHU KANG': 912.5, 'CLEMENTI': 1075.0, 'GEYLANG': 1025.0, 'HOUGANG': 925.0, 'JURONG EAST': 1000.0, 'JURONG WEST': 987.5, 'KALLANG': 1050.0, 'LIM CHU KANG': 0, 'MARINE PARADE': 0, 'PASIR RIS': 952.5, 'PUNGGOL': 0, 'QUEENSTOWN': 1150.0, 'SEMBAWANG': 0, 'SENGKANG': 0, 'SERANGOON': 983.33, 'TAMPINES': 1025.0, 'TOA PAYOH': 1050.0, 'WOODLANDS': 885.0, 'YISHUN': 875.0}</td>
      <td>{'ANG MO KIO': 0, 'BEDOK': 1150.0, 'BISHAN': 1206.25, 'BUKIT BATOK': 0, 'BUKIT MERAH': 0, 'BUKIT PANJANG': 0, 'BUKIT TIMAH': 0, 'CENTRAL': 0, 'CHOA CHU KANG': 993.75, 'CLEMENTI': 0, 'GEYLANG': 0, 'HOUGANG': 1000.0, 'JURONG EAST': 1100.0, 'JURONG WEST': 1075.0, 'KALLANG': 0, 'LIM CHU KANG': 0, 'MARINE PARADE': 0, 'PASIR RIS': 1070.0, 'PUNGGOL': 0, 'QUEENSTOWN': 0, 'SEMBAWANG': 1010.0, 'SENGKANG': 975.0, 'SERANGOON': 0, 'TAMPINES': 1100.0, 'TOA PAYOH': 0, 'WOODLANDS': 968.75, 'YISHUN': 1000.0}</td>
      <td>{'ANG MO KIO': 0, 'BEDOK': 0, 'BISHAN': 0, 'BUKIT BATOK': 0, 'BUKIT MERAH': 0, 'BUKIT PANJANG': 0, 'BUKIT TIMAH': 0, 'CENTRAL': 0, 'CHOA CHU KANG': 1200.0, 'CLEMENTI': 0, 'GEYLANG': 0, 'HOUGANG': 0, 'JURONG EAST': 0, 'JURONG WEST': 1130.0, 'KALLANG': 0, 'LIM CHU KANG': 0, 'MARINE PARADE': 0, 'PASIR RIS': 1196.25, 'PUNGGOL': 0, 'QUEENSTOWN': 0, 'SEMBAWANG': 0, 'SENGKANG': 0, 'SERANGOON': 0, 'TAMPINES': 1237.5, 'TOA PAYOH': 0, 'WOODLANDS': 1100.0, 'YISHUN': 0}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I have a multi layer dataframe which looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXnRM.png)

I want to plot the 2 layered stacked bar chart with mulitple bar chart. Ex: output would be like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04ys1.png)

I am new to python, any help on doing this would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Please [do not post images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question). Please share the data and the code you have written to solve the issue: the best way is to create a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @medium-dimensional Thank you. I am really not sure how to print the data so it can be easily viewable. The above screenshot when I directly print using print(df). Here is the attachment of data in html format generated using df.to_html() option

Comment: Did you try this tutorial: https://pythonbasics.org/matplotlib-bar-chart/ ?

Comment: @Markus Thank you. yes I have. For the current data which is 3 layered indexed dataframe which I could not understand how to generated mixed plot as shown in my original question.